# xbuild error in NUnit when compiling from clean build outside of Xamarin

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, nunit, xbuild

I'm building a command line tool in Xamarin on Mac OS X. In general my workflow is to build and test within Xamarin Studio. Then I have a release build script that builds on the command line using:

```
xbuild /p:Configuration=Release myTool.sln
```

However, I get errors from a file in my unit testing sub-project that I don't get when building the project normally:

```
Tests.cs(13,6): error CS1729: The type `NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes `1' arguments
Tests.cs(14,6): error CS1729: The type `NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes `1' arguments
Tests.cs(759,20): error CS0117: `NUnit.Framework.Assert' does not contain a definition for `Throws'
```

Note that this is **only when building from a clean project**, freshly synced from git. As soon as I open the solution in Xamarin studio and build from there, then the command line build script works as normal.

Is there something that Xamarin is doing that I should be doing on the command line too?

Comment: I would run a diagnostic build both with xbuild and within Xamarin Studio and see if they are both using the same NUnit assembly. I would guess that the wrong one is being picked up, possibly the older version that ships with Mono.

Comment: Thanks @MattWard! That did indeed seem to be the case. Found the solution and posted the answer to my own question here.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using a default `.gitignore` from somewhere (Xamarin's own?) that was ignoring the `packages` directory. This was fine when running from within Xamarin Studio since it automatically downloads the required packages.

By keeping the right version of NUnit within our repo, it means that team members who don't run Xamarin first are able to build the tool okay.